# Formal (Mathematical) Definition of N-Clan?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

I tried many times to find a formal definition for the following important concepts in Graph Theory and Network Analysis:

**1) N-Clique.**
 **2) N-Clan.**
 **3) K-Plex.**
 **4) K-Core.**

[Reference](http://faculty.ucr.edu/~hanneman/nettext/C11_Cliques.html)

, but unfortunately I could not find a useful results, So does anyone have a ground knowledge or any idea about the formal definitions of these concepts?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure those concepts are "important"? I thought I knew a bit about graph theory, but I've never heard about them until you started asking questions about them the other day ...

Comment: Isn't an *n*-clique just a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) of size $n$?  If you have a publication where these terms are used, please cite it.  If not, perhaps an explanation of your interest in these terms would be helpful.

Comment: please see this tutorial
http://faculty.ucr.edu/~hanneman/nettext/C11_Cliques.html